# How would I test if date is in date range (both strings)?

Tags: delphi, date-range

I have two strings, for example `05.04.2002` and `23.01-2002 - 23.06.2002`.

How would I find out if the date in my first string is between the dates in the second string?

What I have been thinking

```
dateString := '05.04.2002';
dateRangeString := '23.01-2002 - 23.06.2002';

date := StrToDate( dateString );
rangeStart := StrToDate( LeftStr(dateRangeString, 10) );
rangeEnd := StrToDate( RightStr(dateRangeString, 10) );
```

Now from there I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the unit `System.DateUtils` and its function [DateInRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/API:System.DateUtils.DateInRange):

```
var
  dStart, dEnd, d2Test: TDate;
begin
  dStart := StrToDate('25/07/2012');
  dEnd   := StrToDate('29/07/2012');

  d2Test := StrToDate('26/07/2012');

  if DateInRange(d2Test, dStart, dEnd) then
    ShowMessage('In range!');
```

You can also check the fourth parameter of this function (`AInclusive: Boolean = True`)... depending on your need...

Comment: Most excellent answers, both of you. Thanks very much for the quickness as well!

Comment: Hm... I cannot find any `DateInRange` function. I guess it was introduced after Delphi 2009?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: It has been added with the XE version: [available](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/DateUtils) ; [not available](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/DateUtils)

Answer (score 3):

A `TDateTime` variable is essentially a `double` variable, and the order between two date-time values (considered as date-time values) is the same as the order between the values considered as real numbers.

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  d1, d2, d: TDate;
begin
  d1 := StrToDate('2012-07-25');
  d2 := StrToDate('2012-07-29');

  d := StrToDate('2012-07-26');

  if (d1 <= d) and (d <= d2) then
    ShowMessage('In range!');
end;
```

Of course, using `Math`, you can also write

```
  if InRange(d, d1, d2) then
      ShowMessage('In range!');
```

Comment: For some reason, my IDE currently refuses to display the declaration of `TDateTime` (Ctrl-Click doesn't work), but I'd suppose it is actually declared as `TDateTime = type double`, so that custom property editors can be used.

Comment: Most excellent answers, both of you. Thanks very much for the quickness as well!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I'd like to add to this is that if the dates are formatted YYYY-MM-DD then you can simply compare them to determine if one is within a range.  No need to convert them to TDateTime first.

```
R1 := '2012-01-01';
R2 := '2012-01-31';
D := '2012-01-15';

if (D >= R1) and (D <= R2) then
  // within range
```